# Matplotlib Pylab Loadtxt Error

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have a .txt file I can clearly open using notepad and excel, trying to import it using matplotlib to plot as a colormap using the py.loadtxt function gives the following error

```
 fh = iter(open(fname, 'U'))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\cr458\\Desktop\\Strathclyde\\C5610A\\Fits\\Area@mAarea.txt'
```

the file directory address is definitely right, and the file can be opened in matlab. I've also tried opening other .txt data files with matplotlib in my interpreter and it has worked fine, I'm thinking maybe it's an issue to do with the format of encoding for the .txt file but am not sure?

Comment: It can't find the file to try to load it in the first place, so the problem is likely with `fname`. What version of python are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using 2.7.6 with Anaconda 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! The slashes were in the wrong direction, despite the fact that I copied and pasted the address ( which may have been the issue in the first place)